# Trying to write a shell for cakephp to use in a cron job

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron

I've written a model and controller method that I wanted to use via a cron job, however on investigation it appears I have to do this as a shell withn Console/Command. I've read a few various SO posts and the manual but its all a little over my head.

This is what I have so far - pretty much ripped from what I had in my model and controller. Could someone give me some pointers on how to get this to work? Thank in advance.

**** EDIT - This now works ****

```
<?php 

App::uses('Shell', 'Console');
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

class OldClaimsShell extends AppShell {

    // Include the ExpesesCLaim mdel
    public $uses = array('ExpenseClaim');


    /**
     * When fired it checks for claims over 7 days that are still "submitted" and have therefore not been dealt with. Function has to be called MAIN - see cake docs
     */
    public function main() {

        // Find all claims with status "submitted" that are older than 7 days
        $answer = $this->ExpenseClaim->haveClaimsOlderThan7Days();

        //debug($answer);
        if ($answer === true) {

            $Email = new CakeEmail();
            $Email->domain('www.xxx.co.uk');
            $Email->template('oldExpenseClaimReminder');
            $Email->to('xxx@xxx.co.uk');
            $Email->from('xx@xx.co.uk');
            $Email->subject('There are outstanding claims over 7 days old - Please Review');
            $Email->viewVars(array('link' => 'http://xxx.xxx.co.uk'));
            $Email->emailFormat('both');
            $Email->send();

            //$this->out('Email sent');
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Amended question based on answer and comments - this now works although Cron doesnt. Will be exploring this in another question.

Comment: haveClaimsOlderThan7Days() should be in the model layer. email is missing domain() for CLI - you should add that as documented. Other than that just setup a cronjob using crontab for example as documented here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html / http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/05/24/cakephp-console-on-linux-systems/

Comment: Thanks for your help - Do I have to load the Expenses Model in the shell?

Comment: yes, either via $uses or ClassRegistry::init(). the first is probably better.

Comment: Sorry, also do I need to include the first line - import('Core', 'Controller'); ? I found that in a blog article but couldnt understand if it was needed in my case.

Comment: You never use App::import for internal classes (only for vendor files), always use App::uses() instead. And in your case, no. You only need to App::uses() those classes you are using (your AppShell and CakeEmail that is! see https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/Console/Command/WhitespaceShell.php for example).

Comment: Hi mark, I'm having a nightmare setting up the cron job as my host doesnt let me add cake to my system $PATH. Is it possible to this shell via a cron job without using the cakeshell bash file it tells you to create? as it says "However, when you have added the console path to the PATH variable via ~/.profile, it will be unavailable to the cronjob." Well I can't do that (due to my shared hosting) so how can I call the shell via a cron job? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've tried the below with no success - any idea? Really pulling my hair out now!

* * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /XXXX/homepages/XXX/XXXXX/htdocs/DevExpenseaApp/lib/Cake/Console/cake --app /XXXXX/homepages/XX/XXXXXX/htdocs/DevExpenseApp/app MyShell

Comment: @JamesJ It's better if you'd update your question with the lines of information you posted in the comments ;-)

Comment: @Jelmer Added updates to code and cron example - any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @JamesJ can you call the shell manually? So pluging the command you are running in the cronjob in the command line? Have you checked the log files? Have tried to figure out if it even calls the method at all? Because if it does, it doesn't help to check the crontab :-)

Comment: @Jelmer Valid point - on checking this it seems console isnt executing it just displays php. Obviously need to look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.x you should **not** `use app::import()`

You should **not** use controllers in shells

The latest 2.x branch has CakeEmail class which is for email from shells, models, controllers etc. (eg: wherever you like) EmailComponent is now a wrapper for this to keep backwards compatibility.

As far as code goes, shells are similar to controllers. You can specify the model to use like you would in a controller and fetching data is exactly the same.

Check the docs on sending emails, its pretty simple...

```
$Email = new CakeEmail();
// set config, add users, etc
$Email->send();
```

Then you run it in the cron with the usual

```
0 * * * * /path/to/app/Console/cake FooBar --params... etc
```

Comment: Shell now works thank you - cron doesnt though - will open a new question for this would love your input. Thanks.